# Visual Studio Cloud Explorer fails: Unable to retrieve subscription

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and trying to connect to my Azure account to do some remote debugging.  When I would sign in with my account, it would sign me in then say:

> Unable to retrieve subscriptions. Try refreshing.

I had a few Azure accounts. I deleted one and they all disappeared. So then I tried to add the one I care about right now and I still get the same error.

Any idea what the problem and/or solution could be?  Thanks so much!

Update: Server Explorer also fails. 
[image]

Comment: Restarting my computer, removing and readding the account didn't fix it. I then turned on Fiddler to try to capture the network call that might provide some insight and it suddenly started working in Visual Studio. I think maybe it got scared and agreed to comply. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not a great workaround, but VS15 Cloud Explorer is still working while VS17 is not.

Also, up vote here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/76138/cloud-explorer-unable-to-show-subscriptions.html

Answer (score 1):

For me, it turned out I had two identical credential tokens and that gave me the "Try refreshing" error message.

These steps solved the issue:

1. Shut down Visual Studio
2. Open the Windows Credential Manager
3. Look for duplicates starting with "WindowsLive:(token)"
4. Remove one of them
5. The subscriptions should now show up in Visual Studio, under Cloud Explorer -> Account Management

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a try. I think this issue eventually resolved itself, but I will try this if I ever run into it again.